# GridView onItemClick not being called?

Tags: android, gridview, view, onclick, listener

I have a gridview with custom views in it. The custom views are view that contain a few buttons. When I onItemClick the gridview to create the custom view, everything works fine, the GridView understands what I am trying to do; but as soon as I onItemLongClick a custom view (that has been created due to an onItemClick), it doesn't register at all. I don't get it, I'm always returning true at the end of the longClick. But if I fill the gridview with a simple image view, both types of click work...

As far as I've read from the android UI handling article all listeners will trickle top-down, so I figured that the event would fire at the gridview before hitting the custom view...

Any thoughts or Ideas?

```
@Override public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
    Log.e("Grid", "Log long click"); 
    mSelect = pos;
    mHold = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mGridWidgets[pos].toBitmap(), getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, true);
    mIsHolding = true;
    setOnTouchListener(mToucher);
    Log.e("Grid", mSelect + "");
    mBoundService.vibrator.vibrate(150);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I t'was stupid. I needed to intercept the MotionEvent.